# vim - surround text with function call

Tags: vim, surround

I want to wrap some code :

```
myObj.text;
```

with a function call where the code is passed as an argument.

```
console.log(myObj.text);
```

I've thought about using surround.vim to do that but didn't manage to do it.

Any idea if it's possible ? I

Comment: I made a plugin based on tpope's vim-surround that includes this: but more generally [vim-surround-funk](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-surround-funk) also allows you to delete, change and yank a surrounding function call, and paste it around any text object (and there's a text object for function calls, so you can paste it around them too!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With Surround in normal mode:

```
ysiwfconsole.log<CR>
```

With Surround in visual mode:

```
Sfconsole.log<CR>
```

---

Without Surround in normal mode:

```
ciwconsole.log(<C-r>")<Esc>
```

Without Surround in visual mode:

```
cconsole.log(<C-r>")<Esc>
```

But that's not very scalable. A mapping would certainly be more useful since you will almost certainly need to do it often:

```
xnoremap <key> cconsole.log(<C-r>")<Esc>
nnoremap <key> ciwconsole.log(<C-r>")<Esc>
```

which brings us back to Surround, which already does that—and more—very elegantly.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the "f" char to input a function. How did you find out ? I haven't seen it in the help doc.

Comment: I… don't remember. Either I learned it from someone else or I found about it by reading the source.

Comment: Is it possible to delete a surrounding function, similar to `dsb` `ds'` etc.?

Comment: @ArturTagisow there is no built-in function text object. If you manage to come up with a reasonably generic one then you will need to turn it into a pseudo-text object to be used as operator-pending motion, which is beyond the scope of this question/answer/comment thread.

Answer (score 7):

I know and use two different ways to accomplish this:

---

#### Variant 1:

1. Select the text you want to wrap in visual mode (hit `v` followed by whatever movements are appropriate).
2. **Replace** that text by hitting `c`, then type your function call `console.log()`. (The old text is not gone, it's just moved into a register, from where it will be promptly retrieved in step 3.) Hit `<esc>` while you are behind the closing parenthese, that should leave you on the `)` character.
3. Paste the replaced text into the parentheses by hitting `P` (this inserts before the character you are currently on, so right between the `(` and the `)`).

The entire sequence is `v<movement>c<functionName>()<esc>P`.

---

#### Variant 2:

Alternatively to leaving insert mode and pasting from normal mode, you can just as well paste directly from insertion mode by hitting `<ctrl>R` followed by `"`.

The entire sequence is `v<movement>c<functionName>(<ctrl>R")<esc>`.

Comment: <strg>R being <ctrl>R (Ctrl-R) for those not familiar with <strg> - I hadn't seen that before, I guess it's German for Ctrl.

Comment: @TerryBrown Right. Thanks. It's fixed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use substitution instruction combined with visual mode

To change `bar` to `foo(bar)`:

1. press `v` and select text you want (plus one more character) to surround with function call (`^v$` will select whole text on current line including the newline character at the end)
2. type `:s/\%V.*\%V/foo\(&\)/<CR>`

Explanation:

- `s/a/b/g` means 'substitute first match of `a` with `b` on current line'
- `\%V.*\%V` matches visual selection **without last character**
- `&` means 'matched text' (`bar` in this case)
- `foo\(&\)` gives 'matched text surrounded with `foo(...)` '
- `<CR>` means 'press enter'

Notes

- For this to work you have to visually select also next character after `bar` (`^v$` selects also the newline character at the end, so it's fine)
- might be some problems with multiline selections, haven't checked it yet
- when I press `:` in visual mode, it puts `'<,'>` in command line, but that doesn't interfere with rest of the command (it even prevents substitution, when selected text appears also somewhere earlier on current line) - `:'<,'>s/...` still works